# Forwarding or exporting a client certificate in IIS6/7

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

Currently, our program runs on JBoss and sits behind an apache reverse proxy.  Apache handles verifying the client certificate.  We have the +ExportCertData option set in apache, and then we use

```
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}e"
```

to put the cert in the header field SSL_CLIENT_CERT before forwarding to JBoss.  Our application in Jboss then reads the cert looking for the SubjectAltName to get the e-mail address, which we use to save the user a step in entering it in.

Now, we will have to live behind IIS, and will need similar functionality to this.  What we really care about is extracting the email address from the SubjectAltName.  In an ideal world, IIS would provide the same information as apache, so we wouldn't have to modify our application code too much.  But if it's not possible, other options are good as well.

Some other notes:

- We will probably need to support IIS6 and IIS7.  It would be nice to have one solution that works across both, but not necessary
- We are currently using IIRF to forward requests that go to a certain virtual directory, but I would be interested in hearing other solutions that could accomplish what we're looking for along with forwarding to our application server.
- Just throwing apache in front of IIS isn't going to be a solution because we have to share the box with other programs that use IIS and they might be wary of such a solution.  Also, we can't just run on a different port because of firewall restrictions only allow port 80 and port 443.

Any ideas how to make this possible? Let me know if there's any more information I can provide.

Comment: I noticed this question was still out here.  I don't think there is any way to do it currently, without writing some type of custom functionality or modifying IIRF.